# Extract frames from video draw shape to frames and encode as video

Tags: android

I am working on video processing app where i have to draw some shape on video like circle,line etc on video and save as mp4 file so when user play again video shows shapes as part of video, in sort i have to extract frames from video, modify them then replace the frames with edited frames.

Please let know how can i achieve this using without third party library or with it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi jain, have you got solution? bcz i want to do this, please help me if any idea. i don't know where i am start n i hope you will help me...! thank you

Comment: Yes you can use FFMPEG library for extracting frames from video

Comment: Whats about making the mp4 file again? Did you use MediaMuxer?